How to write a REGEXP_EXTRACT expression in Google Cloud Logging config json?
I am trying to extract the value at the end of this log:
Chat request completed in 3.818780105999849
This is a log saved in Google Cloud Logging and the message is written in the textPayload field. I am trying to create a log-based metric using the gcloud logging metrics create command (docs found here). Since I am trying to create a distribution metric, I am required to create a config file for the metric.
This is what I have for the config json:
{
    "name": "end-to-end-response-time-shell",
    "description": "Time duration of a chat request (in seconds).",
    "filter": "resource.type=\"cloud_run_revision\" AND logName=\"log_name\" AND severity=\"INFO\" AND textPayload=~\"Chat request completed in\"",
    "metricDescriptor": {
        "name": "cloud_run_revision",
        "type": "logging.googleapis.com/user/end-to-end-response-time-shell",
        "metricKind": "CUMULATIVE",
        "valueType": "DISTRIBUTION",
        "unit": "s",
        "description": "Time duration of a chat request (in seconds).",
        "displayName": "end-to-end-response-time-shell (sec)"
    },
    "valueExtractor": "REGEXP_EXTRACT(textPayload, \"\\s(\\d+\\.*\\d*)\\s\")"
}

The command is erroring at the valueExtractor field with this error message:
ERROR: (gcloud.logging.metrics.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Failed to parse extractor expression: syntax error at line 1, column 29, token '"\s(\d+\.*\d*)\s"'
How should I write the regex expression for this task?

Ugh... nested and escaped RegExs....fun! It's invalid JSON .... I think you either (!?) need a backslash before the penultimate "... Not the last " that terminates the JSON value but the one before it that terminates the REGEXP_EXTRACT value ("...") or you've one too many )"

@DazWilkin You're absolutely right, I added an extra )" while creating my question, that is my fault. But I actually had it as "REGEXP_EXTRACT(textPayload, \"\\s(\\d+\\.*\\d*)\\s\")" and it still gave me an error.

I think you'll need to double-escape (yeah!) the RegEx. In the documentation for REGEXP_EXTRACT, the RegEx value is escaped in the string. You'll have to re-escape it for your escaped string in JSON ..... e.g. \\\\s and \\\\d etc.

NOTE Google's excellent APIs Explorer provides an alternative mechanism to test this projects.metrics.create method alongside the type definitions.

@DazWilkin Your quadruple escape worked!! Please mark it as an answer. Thank you again for your help.

I think you'll need to double-escape (yeah!) the RegEx.
In the documentation for REGEXP_EXTRACT, the RegEx value is escaped in the string.
You'll want to re-escape it for your escaped string in JSON ..... e.g. \\\\s and \\\\d etc.
